# Compare two dataframes without taking into account one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how to compare two df's and keep the values ​​that are in the first df but not in the second without taking into account the Timestamp column since it is different because it reflects when the program was executed.

If there is a row that is in df2 and not in 1, I do not want that row since I am only interested in what is in df1 and not in df2

Dataframe 1:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-02-15 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-10-17 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-10-02 | 2021-05-16 |
| A1 | B2 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B2 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 | 2021-05-16 |

Dataframe 2:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 2022-01-15 | 2022-02-15 | 2021-05-16 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-15 | 2021-10-17 | 2021-05-16 |
| A1 | B1 | 2021-07-30 | 2021-10-02 | 2021-05-15 |
| A1 | B3 | 2021-07-02 | 2021-08-04 | 2021-05-14 |

Result:

| A | B | Start | End | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B2 | 2022-01-01 | 2023-01-01 | 2021-05-17 |
| A1 | B2 | 2021-06-02 | 2021-06-04 | 2021-05-16 |

Thanks!

Comment: ```df.compare(df2)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing rows from 2 dataframes, you can always go with [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.merge.html). Here we’re using it with:

- `on=[…]` with the columns to compare,
- `how='outer'` to include rows that are in one dataframe but not the other
- `indicator=True` to know from which dataframe rows come
- `suffixes` set so that the remain columns you want to keep are unchanged

```
>>> df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['A', 'B', 'Start', 'End'], how='outer', suffixes=('', '_other'), indicator=True)
>>> df
    A   B       Start         End   Timestamp Timestamp_other      _merge
0  A1  B1  2022-01-15  2022-02-15  2021-05-17      2021-05-16        both
1  A1  B1  2021-07-15  2021-10-17  2021-05-17      2021-05-16        both
2  A1  B1  2021-07-30  2021-10-02  2021-05-16      2021-05-15        both
3  A1  B2  2022-01-01  2023-01-01  2021-05-17             NaN   left_only
4  A1  B2  2021-06-02  2021-06-04  2021-05-16             NaN   left_only
5  A1  B3  2021-07-02  2021-08-04         NaN      2021-05-14  right_only
>>> df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'left_only', df1.columns]
    A   B       Start         End   Timestamp
3  A1  B2  2022-01-01  2023-01-01  2021-05-17
4  A1  B2  2021-06-02  2021-06-04  2021-05-16
```